# SQL Server - Split business process in days starting at 00:00:00 and end at 23:59:59

Tags: sql, datetime

I have the following problem which I try to solve (I've tried with PIVOT but didn't came to far...)

Listed are 3 processes which flows from one date into the other (here from April, the 1st until April the 3rd)

```
<Process>   <StartTask1>        <StartTask2>        <StartTask3>        <StartTask4>
1       01.04.2014 23:30    02.04.2014 00:30    02.04.2014 02:30    02.04.2014 04:30
2       02.04.2014 05:30    02.04.2014 07:30    02.04.2014 12:30    02.04.2014 14:30
3       02.04.2014 17:30    02.04.2014 21:30    03.04.2014 03:30    03.04.2014 05:30
```

What would be great to have is a report for the 2nd of April like this:
2.04.2014 (ONLY between 00:00 and 23:59:59 on 2nd of April)

Total time between task1 and task2: 30 + 120 + 240 = 390 minutes

Total time between task2 and task3: 120 + 300 + 150 = 570 minutes

Total time between task3 and task4: 120 + 120 + 0 = 240 minutes

Total time between task 4 and task1: 60 + 180 = 240 minutes

So that we have in total the 1440 minutes per day.
(In this case **only** the date of 2nd of April between 00:00:00 and 23:59:59)

```
Task1-Task2     Task2-Task3     Task3-Task4     Task4-Task1
390 minutes     570 minutes     240 minutes     240 minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #temp
(
    id int IDENTITY(1,1),
    task1 datetime,
    task2 datetime,
    task3 datetime,
    task4 datetime,
)

insert into #temp values    ('20140401 23:30','20140402 00:30','20140402 02:30','20140402 04:30'),
                            ('20140402 05:30','20140402 07:30','20140402 12:30','20140402 14:30'),
                            ('20140402 17:30','20140402 21:30','20140403 03:30','20140403 05:30')

declare @refdate datetime = '20140402'
declare @refdate2 datetime = '20140403'

select sum(case when totaltimes.minutes1 < 0 then 0 else totaltimes.minutes1 end) as totalminutes1,
       sum(case when totaltimes.minutes2 < 0 then 0 else totaltimes.minutes2 end) as totalminutes2,
       sum(case when totaltimes.minutes3 < 0 then 0 else totaltimes.minutes3 end) as totalminutes3



from #temp
cross apply(values(case when task1 < @refdate then @refdate else task1 end,case when task1 > @refdate2 then @refdate2 else task1 end)) as a1(tstart,tend)
cross apply(values(case when task2 < @refdate then @refdate else task2 end,case when task2 > @refdate2 then @refdate2 else task2 end)) as a2(tstart,tend)
cross apply(values(case when task3 < @refdate then @refdate else task3 end,case when task3 > @refdate2 then @refdate2 else task3 end)) as a3(tstart,tend)
cross apply(values(case when task4 < @refdate then @refdate else task4 end,case when task4 > @refdate2 then @refdate2 else task4 end)) as a4(tstart,tend)
cross apply(values(DATEDIFF(minute,a1.tstart,a2.tend), DATEDIFF(minute,a2.tstart,a3.tend), DATEDIFF(minute,a3.tstart,a4.tend))) as totaltimes(minutes1,minutes2,minutes3)

drop table #temp
```

Comment: Hi Hatsjoem! First of all many thanks for the solution! Its in the right direction, but I think the last column is missing (the time between task4 and task1 of a new process).

Comment: Oh yea I forgot that, but I didn't know how you calculated the 60 and 180 minutes.

Comment: The time between Process 1 StartTask4 and Process2 StartTask1 (the time between the 2 processes) are 60 minutes: 4:30->5:30 = 60 minutes
The same between StartTask4 (Process 2) and StartTask1 (Process 3): 14:30-17:30 = 180 minutes.